# Construct a grouping column in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012-express

I have created a table that looks something like this:

```
ID   TSPPLY_DT    NEXT_DT     DAYS_BTWN   TIME_TO_EVENT   CENSORED   ENDPOINT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    2014-01-01   2014-01-10      10            10             0          0 
1    2014-01-10   2014-01-21      11            21             0          0 
1    2014-01-21     NULL         NULL           21             1          0     
2    2015-04-01   2015-04-30      30            30             0          0
2    2015-04-30   2015-05-03       1            31             0          1
2    2015-05-03   2015-05-06       3            34(should be 3)0          0
2    2015-05-06   2015-05-16      10            44(shouldbe 13)1          0
```

The `TIME_TO_EVENT` column however is not adding up correctly with my code - The idea is to add up the days between until either `ID` changes, `CENSORED` = 1 or `ENDPOINT` = 1.

I think what I need is an addition column where I can sum based on an aggregate of `ID` and `GROUPING`... With an output as follows:

```
ID   TSPPLY_DT    NEXT_DT     DAYS_BTWN   TIME_TO_EVENT   CENSORED   ENDPOINT   GROUPING
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    2014-01-01   2014-01-10      10            10             0          0          A 
1    2014-01-10   2014-01-21      11            21             0          0          A 
1    2014-01-21     NULL         NULL           21             1          0          A     
2    2015-04-01   2015-04-30      30            30             0          0          A
2    2015-04-30   2015-05-03       1            31             0          1          A
2    2015-05-03   2015-05-06       3            3              0          0          B
2    2015-05-06   2015-05-16      10            13             1          0          B
```

So any ideas on how to create the `GROUPING` column? It would be something like IF next rows `ID` is the same as current row, check `CENSORED` AND `ENDPOINT`. If either = 1, for the next row, change the grouping to a new value. Once a new `ID` is reached, reset the `grouping` to A (or whatever arbitrary value) and run the test again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms189794.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function, like this:

```
DATEDIFF(d, TSPPLY_DT, NEXT_DT) AS DAYS_BTWN
```

Now you don't need `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks, but my column DAYS_BTWN is functioning correctly. The issue is specifically in the TIME_TO_EVENT column - If you see the first data example, I've commented the rows that are adding up incorrectly.